# Load resource from class's own JAR file

Tags: java, resources, classpath

When using `Class.getResource()` and supplying a rather common resource name, like `"license.html"`, Java may load a `"license.html"` resource from another JAR file which is listed earlier in the CLASSPATH, but may be completely unrelated to my application. Is there a way to force the ClassLoader to **first** try to load the resource from the same JAR file which my class is in and only if not found, look in other JARs on the CLASSPATH?

Comment: *'common resource name, like `"license.html"`'*  A Good reason to give it an uncommon path, like `"com/our/app/license.html"`.

Comment: Your resources should be named in a way that makes them unambiguous - meaning that if there's a match in another `ClassLoader`, it should be considered. Then you'd `getResources()` to list all such matches.

Comment: +1 to Andrew; think of it the same way as package naming.

Comment: If you need to keep the file on the default package you may try to ask for the classloader of a class that is in that jar file.

Comment: @Juan Yes, I have that class. Anyway, MyClass.class.getResource() may load the wrong resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you could use the [JarURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) if you know the exact jar in which your file resides:

```
jar:<url>!/{entry}
```

Comment: I guess I should be able to find out when having the class file?

Comment: @mstrap If you know the exact jar file in which your license.html file resides this should work, otherwise, back to square one.

Comment: `URL urlToClass = obj.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();`  Note: Requires trust/no security manager, and for applets and JWS, will point back to the server even if cached.

Comment: ..but note the edit to that comment.  ;)  I still feel you should go for 'specific path according to package name'.

Answer (score 3):

> ..common resource name, like "license.html"'

A good reason to give it an uncommon path, for instance according to the `package` name.
E.G.  `"/com/our/app/license.html"` is unlikely to collide with any other `license.html`