# xml FileNotFoundException using slick2D library in java

Tags: java, xml, file, filenotfoundexception, slick2d

```
private ConfigurableEmitter emitter;

File xmlFile = new File("ressources/emitter.xml");
emitter = ParticleIO.loadEmitter(xmlFile);
```

If I launch the project in eclipse, everything will works fine, but after I export my project and use JarSplice to create a .jar file, when I launch the jar file using the command prompt, the program will crash launching a FileNotFoundException, saying  it cannot find the path specified.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ressources\emitter.xml (The system cannot find the
path specified)
```

The surprising thing is that just before opening the xml file, I open a .png file located at the same place as the xml file, and this without any problem. In addition, when I open the .jar file I exported using winrar, I can find my xml file under the ressources folder. What can be the problem here?

Thank you!

EDIT :

Code with solution:

```
InputStream i=this.getClass().getClassLoader().
    getResourceAsStream("ressources/test.xml");
emitter = ParticleIO.loadEmitter(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pack your project to JAR your resource don't live on disk, but are compressed into the JAR itself and you have to load as resource.
There are a lot of guide on SO on how to load resource from JAR  using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStrem()` (follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499594/load-resource-from-classs-own-jar-file))

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this much, but can you please tell me how to use your solution in my code? I really can't manage to get it to work :(. And also, how come manage to laod the .png file, but not the .xml file, when they're both located in the same folder? Thank you really much